# MediaWiki payment gateway

Tags: php, wiki, mediawiki, payment-gateway

I would like to have a subscription sponsored wiki in MediaWiki. I want the paid members to have access to certain part of the wiki. How do I achieve that?

Is there a plugin/extension or does it need a rewrite?

In any case, how do I implement the payment gateway if I was flagging the paid users in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Page Access Restriction extension: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_access_restriction and a special group for paid members.

edit: That being said [mediawiki doesn't reccomend you do it...](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Restrict_viewing_of_certain_specific_pages)